# Unable to render layers in MapCanvas using PyQGIS/PyQt4

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am trying to get some layers into a MapCanvas and style them.  I am following the PyQgis Cookbook info [here](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/06_canvas.html) but my code is just not working.  I've been spinning my wheels on this for over a week now and there's no one in my office familiar enough with python/qgis.  What am I missing???

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer1)
canvas1.setExtent(layer1.extent())
canvas1.setLayerSet( [QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer1)] )
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'QgsMapCanvasLayer' is not defined
```

In R you just do this:

```
library(rgdal)
nta <- readOGR("my/path", "mylayer")
spplot(nta)
library(sp)
spplot(nta, zcol="symbolAttributes")
```

Comment: [page 20 of this PyQgis Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/pdf/QGIS-testing-PyQGISDeveloperCookbook-ro.pdf) walks you through symbolizing with two groups of ranges, but I can't seem to translate this into a simple, regular categorized classification.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a normal Python file outside QGIS?

Comment: no, python console in qgis desktop 1.8

Comment: `from qgis.gui import *`